# fix subdomain that redirect to the main domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I encountered a problem after I moved the site to new subdomain,

Every time I enter to my website, I am directed to the subdomain. I think its htaccess issues.

I have 2 website , one in the domain and the other in subdomain (previously was in main domain)

(subdomain directory : public_html/store) |
(domain directory : public_html)

subdomain htaccess file :

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the corresponding database's siteurl and home values as those might both have the subdomain address in them; replace them with the desired domain name, save and see if that doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have a read of this article:
https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/

Additionally, you can access your `wp_options` table via phpmyadmin, and update `siteurl` and `home` to the new address.